# Filtering using Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex

I am having a filter for the following regular expressions

```
[^@()[]\;:,<>]+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/
```

I need to negate the following special charters before the @domain.com

```
@()[]\;:",<
```

any suggestions??

Comment: What do you mean by "negate"?  Do you want to substitute a new value in a variable using a regex?

Comment: simply put [a-zA-Z]+[0-9]* before @

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping the `]` in the character class.

```
[^@()[\]\;:,<>]+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/
      ^^
```

If not escaped the `]` will be treated incorrectly as the end of the character class.

Since this has been tagged as Java, remember that you need to escape using `\\` and not just `\`.

Comment: @harishtps: Just put it in the character class with escaping once with \ .